# Photo Stream & iCloud turned on - but Photos taken on iPhone don't appear on iPad

Tags: icloud, photo-stream

I have iOS 5 on my iPhone and have iCloud set up. I also have turned Photo Stream on. I have an original iPad that also has iOS 5 and also has iCloud & Photo Stream enabled. When I take pictures on my iPhone, they do not appear on my iPad. I went to my iCloud settings (Storage & Backup to make sure that iCloud backup was on. (It was.) I hit “back up now”.     Only the 10 or so pictures I took that morning with my iPhone appear on my iPad now. I took some more photos and checked it several hours later, and the new ones do not appear on my iPad.

What am I missing? The way I understand it, I shouldn’t have to do anything to get iPhone pics to appear, as long as I have iCloud enabled on both and Photo Stream enabled?

I suppose there is no way to get older iPhone photos (taken a few weeks ago) to appear on my Photo Stream? At this point, I’d just be happy if I could get it to stream the ones that I’ve taken since I got iOS 5 & iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Photo Stream definitively only works for photos (or screenshots) taken *after* it was enabled.

As for your other problem: Yes, if you are logged into the same iCloud account on both devices and have Photo Stream enabled it should sync whenever you are logged in into a Wi-Fi environment (apparently Photo Stream doesn't sync over 3G).

What else can you try:

- Take a screenshot on the iPad, make sure you are in a Wi-Fi environment and see whether the screenshot appears on the iPhone
- Log in to iCloud from your computer (requires Lion or a recent Windows version of course) and see whether the photos get streamed there

Comment: See if putting your iPad on charge makes a difference.  I think that for the iTunes sync/backup for example, the devices needs to be not only on the same network, but also on charge before it will do it's thing.

Comment: It's worth doing a restart too.